# How can I protect my photos from Apps?

Tags: security, images

Camera saves them on SD, so everything can just upload them wherever it wants.

I heard of apps that claim to protect photos within them but the only thing they did is making them hidden from the user with hidden folders, but thats not what I call protection.
It also doesnt protect them from apps which dont care about dotted .files or .nomedia.

Is this lack of protection intended?
What can I do?

PS: If the protector you recommend is an app, please let it be one that is available on the developers site because I have no access to playstore.

Comment: Consider buying a dedicated camera and not using the camera on your phone.

Comment: Best thing I heard today!

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid there is no real protection possible, for multiple reasons:

- as you stated, all apps can read everywhere on the SDCard. This does not require any special permission
- apps with the `INTERNET` permission are not restricted in using the network in any way -- they even can create their own sockets and implement their own ways of communication
- while using an encrypted container would look promising on a first look, the camera app could not access this container either when it's not opened -- and if the container is opened, other apps could access it as well. So even using such a container and have it replacing `/sdcard/DCIM` does not work for your purpose

Summed up: if you want that level of protection, you either...

- cannot use any app requiring the `INTERNET` permission (no way for that, as several of them already come pre-installed with your device)
- need to root your device and set up a firewall forbidding all apps to access the internet (which, outside the EU, would void your warranty)
- need to have mobile-data as well as WiFi disabled all the time, and never connect your device to any network

As none of the above is really practicable, you need to compromise: When selecting the apps you want to install/use, check beforehand how trustworthy they are -- and keep your fingers away from "suspicious apps" as well as "suspicious sources".

As long as you're only concerned about the photos you take: If you find a camera app which can use an encrypted container solely by itself, this might be a way to go (I never heard of such, but it would be possible to create it, so it might exist). Another possible thing would be a "container app" that lets you specify which apps are permitted to access it. But keep in mind that your gallery app (which you use to view the photos) most likely will have the `INTERNET` permission as well...

**EDIT:** As [Compro01](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/23562/compro01) pointed out in his comment below, with Android 4.1 and up you can add some protection by enabling the "protect SD Card" item in the developer options. If that is activated, apps (including your camera app) need to have the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` respective `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to access the SDCard.

Moreover, [PerennialPinömpel](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/31078/perennialpinompel) found an app named
[InformaCam](https://dev.guardianproject.info/projects/informacam/wiki/Overview):

> InformaCam, part of the SecureSmartCam suite of mobile apps, is a tool that allows users to embed expansive metadata into video or still images; encrypt media to trusted destinations using PGP; and securely upload media to trusted destinations who are capable of accepting InformaCam media.

Unfortunately, neither that app nor the full suite is available on Google Play currently. I also could not find an `.apk` on the mentioned site, so one would have to clone its Git repository, and compile the app.

Comment: Okay and outside of the android permsiion world? Any Root-tool mod or similar?

Comment: How can the situation be so much worse than on desktop?

Comment: Ah didnt recognize the last section, did you edit?

Comment: I found this: https://dev.guardianproject.info/projects/informacam/wiki/Overview

Comment: How can it be "better" on desktop? All your computer programms can do the same, and do not need any explicit "Internet" permission. And no, I did not edit my answer (yet) -- you would see an "edited" remark like on your question (where I only added the "security" tag). // The app you've found seems a valid answer to your question; unfortunately, it seems not to be available in the playstore...

Comment: There are actually permissions to control SD card access (`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`), but these are not enforced by default.  You can force enforcement of these in 4.1 and later by enabling "protect SD card" in the developers options.  But if an app does have permission, they can still do whatever they like to anything on the SD card.

Comment: @Izzy - I think you misread the question.  He's specifically wanting apps that aren't only available in the play store.

Comment: @Compro01 the answer is also for other interested users. And the OP didn't specify the app must *not* be available on GooglePlay -- only that it should (also) be available at a place where he can pick the `.apk` directly (others might be hesistant to do the latter -- aside from the fact that there's no `.apk` on the InformaCam site either). The question further is not about *Is there an app for X* (which would be off topic), but about possible solutions.

Comment: an hour of searching through links from the tor and activist millieu did not bring up anything  promising..       if an actual solution is available in play store only so be it, but i have not found one there either. yes I search for a solution, regardless if its an app, android modification or linux-userspace-y stuff thats could be in customroms.  As for now the only valid approach I see is modifying android or on top of that cyanogenmod at source level for whatever I could think of. too bad I am really inexperienced in that field, particularly for android.

Comment: The answer block is quite informative now, should I mark it answered or wait until there is really a solution?

Comment: That's completely up to you. Even if you mark it now, and tomorrow comes an answer which seems better fitting, you can "switch over" and accept the other instead (which would remove the "Accepted" checkmark from this one). If you estimate your chances of a better answer higher when there's no "accepted" answer already present, you can also wait.